# Dynamically modify title of a series

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

After line chart renders completely; I want to modify the legends of the chart. This is because I get generic names like value1, value2 etc as response from the server.
I have tried to change the legend by changing the title of the series dynamically but it has not worked so far.

I could find a way by modifying the Ext JS library as mentioned here.
http://standalone.iteye.com/blog/1074517

But i need to do it within the ambit of my code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer of my question.

**Series** of the chart provides listeners events; which supports multiple methods. `afterrender` method can be used to modify the title of the **series**.

```
listeners: {
            'afterrender': function() {
                this.setTitle('yourTitle');
            }
    }
```

In above method you can set any custom value for your title.